iTerm2 adds extra characters when pasting
I am developing on a MacBook Pro OS 14.5 and use iTerm2 3.5.3
Since I am originally a Linux user I do a lot of copy and paste with my mouse: copying via marking the text in iTerm2 and pasting it via middle click.
Sometimes it works, but sometimes iTerm2 adds extra characters like this
00~gcloud auth application-default login01~

instead of 

gcloud auth application-default login


How can I switch it off since I  copy & paste a lot in the terminal.
If I copy and past with option+C and option+V I have the same problem.

The best answer on the bracketed paste feature seems to be this one. Let me see if others are relevant.

Ok - those three seem to cover all angles of this topic. Please make an edit and flag this for a moderator to look at if your problem ends up being different than the linked questions and accepted answers on them.

The short answer solved the problem for me!

Reset? Or unset zle_bracketed_paste either way very glad. This one is a bit tricky to search when you don’t know what bracketed paste is called.

Exactly! If you know what you are looking for it is much easier :)
